# Simplifying a shapefile (in Python)

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, shapefile, qgis

I have a world political map shapefile that I want to simplify in a manner where the political boundaries are at specific angles — 0, 45, 90, or 135 degrees. An example of that would be [this](https://www.visualcapitalist.com/mapped-which-countries-have-the-highest-inflation/) map.

Is there any way in QGIS or Python to achieve that? Thanks!

I've tried simplifying the file on Mapshaper, but that is not as visually appealing.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you want to use a raster or single points to achive this using a concave hull. Tried it with one geometry (germany, epsg:25832, units:meter) like this:

1. distribute points on a regular grid: vector → research tools → grid → type point, import grid extend from layer, horizontal + vertical spacing 15 kilometers
2. select points within geometry: vector → research tools → select by location. Select features from grid which intersect the polygon
3. swap selected points
4. delete points outside polygon
5. compute concave hull: open processing toolbox → concave hull (k-nearest neighbor). Use the grid and 1 neighboring point

It leads to a result, similar to the linked map. Some manual editing might be needed to add / remove some grid points. To do this for multiple polygons, you would need to aggregate the points by country. You would need to try different gridsizes. Be aware, that worldwide data is often stored as lat/lon. So you could try gridsizes like 0.5 or 0.25 degrees.

[image: data steps in QGIS]